# how to hide the title bar or window in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter, pyqt5

i want to hide my window or tittle bar of my window. as i want to show the output of the opencv frameless.

tell me how can i do that with the help of tkinter or pyqt5.
and also i want the size of the output according to my specation.
and can i resize and change the place of the output like drag and drop anywhere on desktop while the code is running.

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import datetime

date=datetime.datetime.now()
framerate=24
screen_size=(640,480) #std res 640,480
filename='E:/project/videos/cam_%s%s%s%s%s%s.avi' %(date.year,date.month,date.day,date.hour,date.minute,date.second)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
out= cv2.VideoWriter(filename,fourcc,framerate,screen_size)
cv2.namedWindow('frame',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow('frame',280,190)
cv2.moveWindow('frame',5,495)
#cv2.namedWindow('frame',cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)   #use for full screen
#cv2.setWindowProperty('frame', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)



while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:

        frame=cv2.flip(frame,1)


        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break       



cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example using `tkinter` to show the capture images from webcam:

```
import cv2
import datetime
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

screen = Tk()
screen.overrideredirect(1)  # remove window decorations
screen.geometry('280x200+5+520')  # move the window

framerate = 24
screen_size = (640, 480) #std res 640,480

date = datetime.datetime.now()
filename = 'E:/project/videos/cam_%s%s%s%s%s%s.avi' % (date.year, date.month, date.day,
                                                       date.hour, date.minute, date.second)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, framerate, screen_size)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

imgbox = Label(screen)
imgbox.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

def quit(event):
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    screen.destroy()

def read_frame():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        out.write(frame)
        # since openCV capture image is in BGR color sequence
        # so need to convert it to RGB color sequence
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # convert the openCV image to PIL (Pillow) format
        img = Image.fromarray(frame)
        #img = img.resize((280, 200))  # not keep aspect ratio
        img.thumbnail((280, 200))  # keep aspect ratio
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        imgbox.config(image=img)  # update the image
        img.image = img  # keep a reference of the image to avoid being garbage collected
    screen.after(20, read_frame)  # schedule next read after 20 ms

# bind the 'q' key to quit program
screen.bind('q', quit)

read_frame()
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: i am glad you helped me with this and i finally achieved what i wanted. can you also help me with this code **updated question** i am trying to do the same thing with pyqt5 or tkinter any one will do. in my screen recording code.

Comment: You should create another question instead of modifying this one.

Comment: i created another question please visit [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60314233/how-to-start-recording-from-click-of-a-button-in-label-in-python)

Comment: You better resume this question, otherwise my answer does not match with the question.