# how to start recording from click of a button in label in python

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, tkinter

i want to display the output of opencv in this label.
but in this i want to start recording with the click of a start button and stop with stop button and if possible i want to lauch my webcam (previously coded) with the click of start webcam button simentenusly.

```
import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageGrab
import cv2
import numpy as np
import threading
import win32api
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

VIDEO_SIZE = (960, 540)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

date = datetime.datetime.now()
#filename='E:/project/videos/rec_%s%s%s%s%s%s.avi' % (date.year, date.month, date.day,
                                                     #date.hour, date.minute, date.second)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
frame_rate = 12

out = cv2.VideoWriter()
def change_r():
        if rec_btn['text'] == 'Start Recording':
            start_recording()

            rec_btn.config(text="Stop Recoding")
        else:
            stop_recording()

            rec_btn.config(text="Start Recording")
def change_w():
        if cap_btn['text'] == 'Open webcam':
            start_webcam()

            cap_btn.config(text="Close Webcam")
        else:
            stop_webcam(event)

            cap_btn.config(text="Open webcam")
# --- screen capture
def Cursor_pos(img,center,radius,color,thickness):
    center = tuple(map(int,center))
    rgb = [255*c for c in color[:3]] # convert to 0-255 scale for OpenCV
    alpha = color[-1]
    radius = int(radius)
    if thickness > 0:
        pad = radius + 2 + thickness
    else:
        pad = radius + 3
    roi = slice(center[1]-pad,center[1]+pad),slice(center[0]-pad,center[0]+pad)

    try:
        overlay = img[roi].copy()
        cv2.circle(img,center,radius,rgb, thickness=thickness, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
        opacity = alpha
        cv2.addWeighted(src1=img[roi], alpha=opacity, src2=overlay, beta=1. - opacity, gamma=0, dst=img[roi])
    except:
        logger.debug("transparent_circle would have been partially outside of img. Did not draw it.")

def recording_screen():
    global recording
    recording = True
    while recording:
        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        frame = np.array(img)
        _xs,_ys = win32api.GetCursorPos()
        #curpos = root.winfo_pointerx(), root.winfo_pointery()
        Cursor_pos(frame,(_xs,_ys),20,(255,255,0,0.5), -1)
        #cv2.circle(frame, curpos, 10, (0,255,255), 2)
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, VIDEO_SIZE)
        tkimage.paste(Image.fromarray(frame))
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        out.write(frame)

def start_recording():

    if not out.isOpened():
        filename = asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Save as",mode='wb',filetypes = (("Video file","*.avi"),("all files","*.*")),defaultextension=".avi")


        out.open(filename, fourcc, frame_rate, VIDEO_SIZE)
    threading.Thread(target=recording_screen, daemon=True).start()

def stop_recording():
    global recording
    recording = False
    #filename = asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Save as",mode='wb',filetypes = (("Video file","*.avi"),("all files","*.*")),defaultextension=".avi")



# --- webcam

webcam = None
WEBCAM_SIZE = (280, 200)

def read_frame(imgbox):
    if cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, WEBCAM_SIZE)
            image = Image.fromarray(frame)
            imgbox.image.paste(image)
        webcam.after(20, read_frame, imgbox)

def stop_webcam(event):
    global webcam
    if webcam:
        webcam.destroy()
        webcam = None

def start_webcam():
    global webcam
    if webcam is None:
        webcam = tk.Toplevel()
        webcam.geometry('{}x{}+5+520'.format(WEBCAM_SIZE[0], WEBCAM_SIZE[1]))
        webcam.overrideredirect(1)
        imgbox = tk.Label(webcam)
        imgbox.pack()
        imgbox.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.new('RGB',WEBCAM_SIZE,(0,0,0)))
        imgbox.config(image=imgbox.image)
        webcam.bind('<F8>', stop_webcam)
        read_frame(imgbox)

# --- main

root = tk.Tk()

tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.new('RGB', VIDEO_SIZE, (0,0,0)))

w, h = VIDEO_SIZE
vbox = tk.Label(root, image=tkimage, width=w, height=h, bg='black')
vbox.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

rec_btn = ttk.Button(frame, text='Start Recording', width=20, command=change_r)
rec_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

#stop_btn = ttk.Button(frame, text='stop recording', width=20, command=stop_recording, state='disabled')
#stop_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

cap_btn = ttk.Button(frame, text='Open webcam', width=20, command=change_w)
cap_btn.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()

out.release()
cap.release()
```

i want to display my recording like this label of gui by tkinter

> new and updated it is displaying two different frames one with BGR and one with RGB  (how to solve this)

**updated image**

[image]

[image]

Comment: A question asking for answers in different technologies is considered too broad, so I recommend avoiding it. If you want to do the same with 2 technologies then you must post 2 questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an `tkinter` example to capture screen to external video file:

```
import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageGrab
import cv2
import numpy as np
import threading

VIDEO_SIZE = (960, 540)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

date = datetime.datetime.now()
filename='E:/project/videos/rec_%s%s%s%s%s%s.avi' % (date.year, date.month, date.day,
                                                     date.hour, date.minute, date.second)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
frame_rate = 12

out = cv2.VideoWriter()

# --- screen capture

def recording_screen():
    global recording
    recording = True
    while recording:
        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        frame = np.array(img)
        curpos = root.winfo_pointerx(), root.winfo_pointery()
        cv2.circle(frame, curpos, 10, (0,255,255), 2)
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, VIDEO_SIZE)
        tkimage.paste(Image.fromarray(frame))
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        out.write(frame)

def start_recording():
    rec_btn.config(state='disabled')
    stop_btn.config(state='normal')
    if not out.isOpened():
        out.open(filename, fourcc, frame_rate, VIDEO_SIZE)
    threading.Thread(target=recording_screen, daemon=True).start()

def stop_recording():
    global recording
    recording = False
    rec_btn.config(state='normal')
    stop_btn.config(state='disabled')

# --- webcam

webcam = None
WEBCAM_SIZE = (280, 200)

def read_frame(imgbox):
    if cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, WEBCAM_SIZE)
            image = Image.fromarray(frame)
            imgbox.image.paste(image)
        webcam.after(20, read_frame, imgbox)

def stop_webcam(event):
    global webcam
    if webcam:
        webcam.destroy()
        webcam = None

def start_webcam():
    global webcam
    if webcam is None:
        webcam = tk.Toplevel()
        webcam.geometry('{}x{}+5+520'.format(WEBCAM_SIZE[0], WEBCAM_SIZE[1]))
        webcam.overrideredirect(1)
        imgbox = tk.Label(webcam)
        imgbox.pack()
        imgbox.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.new('RGB',WEBCAM_SIZE,(0,0,0)))
        imgbox.config(image=imgbox.image)
        webcam.bind('q', stop_webcam)
        read_frame(imgbox)

# --- main

root = tk.Tk()

tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.new('RGB', VIDEO_SIZE, (0,0,0)))

w, h = VIDEO_SIZE
vbox = tk.Label(root, image=tkimage, width=w, height=h, bg='black')
vbox.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

rec_btn = ttk.Button(frame, text='start recording', width=20, command=start_recording)
rec_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

stop_btn = ttk.Button(frame, text='stop recording', width=20, command=stop_recording, state='disabled')
stop_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

cap_btn = ttk.Button(frame, text='start webcam', width=20, command=start_webcam)
cap_btn.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()

out.release()
cap.release()
```

Also I have used `ImageGrab.grab()` to take screen shot, and `winfo_pointerx()` and `winfo_pointery()` to get the mouse current position because I have not installed `pywin32` and `pyautogui` modules.

Comment: when i run this code the webcam opens up but the frame is stuck and does not capture and by the way i don't wont to capture the webcam in this i want to capture the desktop screen and display the capture of screen in the label. and i want to get the webcam only when the (webcam)button is clicked until that only the desktop screen should be displayed. what i am trying to do here is creating a screen recorder with the webcam feature.

Comment: i want to record my desktop screen and not my webcam. webcam is my secondary objective. please take a look at my code above. it is capturing the screen.

Comment: it is recording the screen but it is not displaying anything its just black screen in the window and when i click on webcam it shows the webcam inside the window that i dont want i want the webcam window as shown above in the question (updated)

Comment: Putting the capture screen into the application window will result in recursive image shown.  Is it what you want?

Comment: Updated the screen capturing part and removed the webcam part as it has been answered in other question.

Comment: updated the image in the question. this is how i want. and as you can see the screen is black. And webcam part which is showing the face in bottom  is (edited) i put it there it is not the output of the code. just to show you how i want.

Comment: sorry for delay now the display is showing the recording with your updated coding. but can you show me how to achieve the webcam also like i edited in that above picture by clicking on the webcam button can i run my previous code of webcam which you answered previously.

Comment: please reply. how can i launch my webcam as a widget from click of webcam button. (the code you provided before) that one.

Comment: @Cb9867 You should move the line `frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)` just before `out.write(frame)`.

Comment: it is working but can i use a function key such as 'F8' to stop the webcam or a stop button to stop the webcam instead of 'q'

Comment: You better try it yourself as it is not difficult to change the code to do what you want.  It is good for you.

Comment: ok i will defiantly try it. but can you tell me how to accept the filename from user instead of datetime one which i am using in this code . how can I use `from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename` and `filename = asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Save as",mode='wb',filetypes = (("Video file","*.avi"),("all files","*.*")),defaultextension=".avi")` to get this?

Comment: Put the code before `out.open(filename, ...)` inside `start_recording()`.

Comment: not working getting errors. i got the close the webcam from button part but filename is not working.

Comment: If you inspect the error carefully, you should fix it easily.  Remove `mode='wb'` from `asksaveasfilename(...)`.  BTW, there is other issues in your updated code: `stop_webcam(event)` should be `stop_webcam(None)` inside `change_w()`.

Comment: i want to ask after the click of stop button and not at the beginning of the video. can i do that by sifting the code to stop button.

Comment: For your current design, no because `out.write(frame)` is kept being called during capturing.

Comment: i am not able to move my webcam window when i use `webcam.overrideredirect(1) ` but when i remove it i can move my webcam but it is showing title bar. i want to drag my webcam and don't want the title bar ?