# How to record only specific selected area of screen

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have a Python program to take a screen shoot of a selected area of desktop screen.

This program get the co-ordinates of the selected area by cursor.

And then crop the image and display the image.

But now I am making a screen recorder and I want to use the co-ordinates of the selected area to record the specific screen area.

This is my area selection code;

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk ,FLAT
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageGrab, ImageEnhance
import cv2
import numpy as np
import threading

VIDEO_SIZE = (800,420)
f = ImageGrab.grab()  
a, b = f.size
filename="test.avi"
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264')
frame_rate = 10
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, frame_rate,(a, b))

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.title('Screen Recorder')
root.geometry('+260+70')
x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0
def show_image(image):
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    tk.Label(win, image=win.image).pack()
    win.grab_set()
    win.wait_window(win)

def area_sel():
    x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0
    roi_image = None

    def on_mouse_down(event):
        nonlocal x1, y1
        x1, y1 = event.x, event.y
        canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1, y1, outline='red', tag='roi')

    def on_mouse_move(event):
        nonlocal roi_image, x2, y2
        x2, y2 = event.x, event.y
        canvas.delete('roi-image') 
        roi_image = image.crop((x1, y1, x2, y2)) 
        canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(roi_image)
        canvas.create_image(x1, y1, image=canvas.image, tag=('roi-image'), anchor='nw')
        canvas.coords('roi', x1, y1, x2, y2)
        canvas.lift('roi') 

    root.withdraw()  
    image = ImageGrab.grab()  
    bgimage = ImageEnhance.Brightness(image).enhance(0.3)  
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.attributes('-fullscreen', 1)
    win.attributes('-topmost', 1)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(win, highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bgimage)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=tkimage, anchor='nw', tag='images')
    win.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', on_mouse_down)
    win.bind('<B1-Motion>', on_mouse_move)
    win.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda e: win.destroy())
    win.focus_force()
    win.grab_set()
    win.wait_window(win)
    root.deiconify()  


    if roi_image:
        start_recording() #calling main function to record screen


def recording_screen():
    global recording
    recording = True

    while recording:

        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
        frame = np.array(img)
        sc = np.array(img)
        sc = cv2.resize(sc, VIDEO_SIZE)
        tkimage.paste(Image.fromarray(sc))
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        out.write(frame)

def start_recording():

    if not out.isOpened():
        out.open(filename, fourcc, frame_rate,(a, b))
    threading.Thread(target=recording_screen, daemon=True).start()

def stop_recording():
    global recording
    recording = False
    out.release()


tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.new('RGB', VIDEO_SIZE, (0,0,0)))

w, h = VIDEO_SIZE
vbox = tk.Label(root, image=tkimage, width=w, height=h, bg='black')
vbox.pack(pady=10,padx=25)

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

sel_area = ttk.Button(frame, text='select area to Record', width=30, command=area_sel)
sel_area.grid(row=0, column=0)

stp_rec = ttk.Button(frame, text='Stop Recording', width=30, command=stop_recording)
stp_rec.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

> Showing errors

```
sc = cv2.resize (sc, VIDEO_SIZE)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv:: UMat> for argument '%s'
```

Comment: ***"want to use the co-ordinates of the selected area to record"***: What is stopping you to do so?

Comment: As I said in the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60769486/how-to-give-dynamic-value-for-area-selection-in-imagegrab-library-in-python/60775548#60775548), you have all the required information and so you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @acw1668 here is my new code [link](https://pastebin.com/VFW6u7Lp) but showing error (the error is updated in the question above).

Comment: Have you read the API document of [`opencv`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#a0901c353cd5ea05bba455317dab81130)?

Comment: What is `dtype` of `sc`?

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf its an array of images.

Comment: Try `print(dtype(sc))` and share the result here.

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: The values inside the array are float? `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` is `type`. `dtype` is usually `float32`, `float16`, or `unit8`.

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf when i try using `print(dtype(sc))` then error shows up `NameError: name 'dtype' is not defined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210575/discussion-between-ibrahim-yousuf-and-arvind8).

Comment: @acw1668 can you correct me where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** The question has been edited since my answer.

Your call to `VideoWriter.open()` is missing arguments.

OpenCV documentation specifies the following arguments to

```
retval = cv.VideoWriter.open(filename, fourcc, fps, frameSize[, isColor] )
```

If your `out.isOpened()` returns `False`. This means your `VideoWriter` initialization has failed and you'll need to specify the arguments.

```
out.open(filename, fourcc, frame_rate,(a, b))
```

Comment: got it,but again showing another error question updated.

Answer (score 1):

Your updated code has several issues:

1) the frame size `(a,b)` of output video does not match with capture image size `VIDEO_SIZE`

```
f = ImageGrab.grab()
a, b = f.size
...
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, frame_rate, (a,b))
```

Just remove `f = ImageGrab.grab()` and `a, b = f.size` and use `VIDEO_SIZE` in `out = cv2.VideoWriter(..., VIDEO_SIZE):

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, frame_rate, VIDEO_SIZE)
```

2) added `x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0` in global space, but does not update them.  So during capture, a zero size image is captured and resized which cause the error mentioned in the question.  Remove the global declaration line and passed the `x1, y1, x2, y2` to `start_recording()` and `recording_screen()` functions.

Below is modified code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk ,FLAT
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageGrab, ImageEnhance
import cv2
import numpy as np
import threading

VIDEO_SIZE = (800,420)
#f = ImageGrab.grab() ### not necessary
#a, b = f.size        ### not necessary
filename="test.avi"
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264')
frame_rate = 10
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, frame_rate, VIDEO_SIZE) # use VIDEO_SIZE

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.title('Screen Recorder')
root.geometry('+260+70')
#x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0  # not necessary
def show_image(image):
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    tk.Label(win, image=win.image).pack()
    win.grab_set()
    win.wait_window(win)

def area_sel():
    x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0
    roi_image = None

    def on_mouse_down(event):
        nonlocal x1, y1
        x1, y1 = event.x, event.y
        canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1, y1, outline='red', tag='roi')

    def on_mouse_move(event):
        nonlocal roi_image, x2, y2
        x2, y2 = event.x, event.y
        canvas.delete('roi-image') 
        roi_image = image.crop((x1, y1, x2, y2)) 
        canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(roi_image)
        canvas.create_image(x1, y1, image=canvas.image, tag=('roi-image'), anchor='nw')
        canvas.coords('roi', x1, y1, x2, y2)
        canvas.lift('roi') 

    root.withdraw()  
    image = ImageGrab.grab()  
    bgimage = ImageEnhance.Brightness(image).enhance(0.3)  
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.attributes('-fullscreen', 1)
    win.attributes('-topmost', 1)
    canvas = tk.Canvas(win, highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bgimage)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=tkimage, anchor='nw', tag='images')
    win.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', on_mouse_down)
    win.bind('<B1-Motion>', on_mouse_move)
    win.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda e: win.destroy())
    win.focus_force()
    win.grab_set()
    win.wait_window(win)
    root.deiconify()  

    if roi_image:
        start_recording((x1, y1, x2, y2)) #calling main function to record screen


def recording_screen(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    global recording
    recording = True

    while recording:
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
        #frame = np.array(img) # not necessary
        sc = np.array(img)
        sc = cv2.resize(sc, VIDEO_SIZE)
        tkimage.paste(Image.fromarray(sc))
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(sc, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        out.write(frame)

def start_recording(region):
    ''' not necessary
    if not out.isOpened():
        out.open(filename, fourcc, frame_rate, VIDEO_SIZE)
    '''
    threading.Thread(target=recording_screen, args=region, daemon=True).start()

def stop_recording():
    global recording
    recording = False
    out.release()


tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.new('RGB', VIDEO_SIZE, (0,0,0)))

w, h = VIDEO_SIZE
vbox = tk.Label(root, image=tkimage, width=w, height=h, bg='black')
vbox.pack(pady=10,padx=25)

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

sel_area = ttk.Button(frame, text='select area to Record', width=30, command=area_sel)
sel_area.grid(row=0, column=0)

stp_rec = ttk.Button(frame, text='Stop Recording', width=30, command=stop_recording)
stp_rec.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the output of the file is empty and of 0bytes

Comment: It works fine in my environment.

Comment: @acw1668 you only specifying `VIDEO_SIZE=(800,420)` then how can the program will record the selected area

Comment: The captured image will be resized to VIDEO_SIZE by the line `sc = cv2.resize(sc, VIDEO_SIZE)`.